# Template engine that takes template and json file and returns html

Tags: html, templates

I'm looking for a template engine that takes a template and a json (or yaml, or similar) and renders this into a html file.
Like this

Template file

```
{{pages}}
<div class="page">
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<ul>
    {{instructions}}
        <li>{{instruction}}</li>
    {{/instructions}}
</div>
{{/pages}}
```

Data File

```
pages:
  - title: My title
    instructions: 
      - Do this
      - Do that
  - title: Another title
    instructions:
      - Click here
      - Click there
```

Which renders:

```
<div class="page">
  <h1>My title</h1>
  <ul>
    <li>Do this</li>
    <li>Do that</li>
</div>
<div class="page">
<h1>Another title</h1>
<ul>
    <li>Click here</li>
    <li>Click there</li>
</div>
```

Is there a way to do get the rendered html as a file, so that I can use it in an other tool like prince?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of tools that can do stuff like this. In no particular order, try...

- [Mustache](https://mustache.github.io/)
- [Jade](http://jade-lang.com/)
- [one of the tools listed here](http://garann.github.io/template-chooser/)

...or just google "template engine".

Comment: Okay mustache looks good, I actually read of this one, but obviously didn't get the point. Thank you!